# In search of a College Leve Pre Algebra Applications Textbook

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, applications

I am looking for a textbook at the college level that mainly focuses on applying algebra to situations. I want students to know how to set up the equations, not just solve them.

Comment: Like an introductory physics book?

Comment: No, like a pre-algebra book that can apply the equations. Also details how to set up the equations.

Comment: Needs clarification: "Pre Algebra" (in title) cannot encompass "applying algebra" (in body).